# How to import a table using power query when the table does not show up in power query editor?

Tags: html-table, datatable, powerquery, export-to-excel, import-from-excel

I am trying to import a table from this webpage:

http://www.eybl.lv/new/ce_u17_game.php?game_id=5746141&season_id=125274#mbt:103-400$t&0=1

When I try to import the table, power query does not find the table in the webpage.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efiLA.png)

I tried importing the webpage as a text file, but I still could not find any of the data from the table in the text file. I can't figure out why the data from the table is not showing up in the code. Could there be a different URL I should be using instead that contains the table? How can I import a table from this webpage into excel using power query? Please help, thanks!

Comment: what is in the data column? Did you click on one of the items in that column to see the contents of the table?

Comment: @horseyride how do I do that?

Comment: It looks like the data is loaded from an external site after the page has loaded. I'm not sure excel can pick that up.

Comment: @Andy that what I was thinking, is there a way to find what that external site is?

Comment: I tried looking, but it is tied to a key that appears to only work from the site requesting it, which makes sense I suppose.